# Could not create constraint in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following code in my migration class.

```
//migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
//    name: "vwEXCommunity",
//    columns: table => new
//    {
//        CommID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
//            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
//        ComName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
//        Statename = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
//        StateID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
//        LGAID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
//        LGAname = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
//    },
//    constraints: table =>
//    {
//        table.PrimaryKey("PK_vwEXCommunity", x => x.CommID);
//    });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "tbService",
    columns: table => new
    {
        sn = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        ServiceNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
        ServiceDesc = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
        LocId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        LandOwnId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        AcqDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
        JobArea = table.Column<double>(type: "float", nullable: false),
        Coord = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
        MntRate = table.Column<double>(type: "float", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_tbService", x => x.sn);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_tbService_TbLandOwners_LandOwnId",
            column: x => x.LandOwnId,
            principalTable: "TbLandOwners",
            principalColumn: "LandOwnId",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_tbService_vwEXCommunity_LocId",
            column: x => x.LocId,
            principalTable: "vwEXCommunity",
            principalColumn: "CommID",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

I commented out vwEXCommunity because I created vwEXCommunity is a view I created linked to another database, and it was not scaffolded into the database, I created it straight on the database.  Now if I update database using

```
update-database
```

I get the following error:

> Foreign key 'FK_TbLandOwners_vwEXCommunity_CommID' references object 'vwEXCommunity' which is not a user table.
> Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

According to EF Core, I am meant to comment out the tables that already exist  after executing the first migration, as -IgnoreErrors don't work anymore. What do I do to update the database, as I need the vwEXCommunity as is.

Comment: Looks like you have to comment out the table.ForeignKey call as well. EF will still have the FK in its model, it's just that the database doesn't have it.

Comment: From EF Core 5, you can declare a entity from a SQL view. See the documentation [Mapping to database objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#mapping-to-database-objects) This part is interesting : `ToView assumes that the object already exists in the database and it won't be created by migrations.`. I never tested this, but it's promising.